# pie charts combined with bubble graph in excel-vba error

Tags: excel, runtime-error, pie-chart, bubble-chart, vba

I need to create pie charts in bubble graph in excel.
I have found a way to it: http://alesandrab.wordpress.com/2013/02/19/create-a-bubble-pie-chart-or-world-map-pie-chart-using-vba-and-excel-charts/

My Data:

[image]

When I run the code I took a error:

[image]

Pls help.

Comment: Have you defined names for your data **"PieChartValues"** in workseet and have you renamed you chart to **"chtMarker"** according to your tutorial (steps 1 and 2)?

Comment: 1) since the macro uses _ActiveSheet_, you should run it only when sheet with your data is active. 2) try to press __debug__ button when the error occured and determin in wich line of code it occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with this one. Turns out that it was the double apostrophe that was causing the issue since I copied and pasted the code. I just had to delete and retype the apostrophes and it worked. It may have been the same case for you.